# Word document properties shows incorrect sharepoint content type

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a document library with 5 content types where 'BZ Document' is the set as default content type :
[image]

By using a javascript button i am opening an word template using [Office URI schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx) eg:
"ms-word:nft|u|https://sharepoint-site-Url/Lists/Templates/CustomWordTemplate.dotm|s|https://sharepoint-site-Url/subject/1932018921/Shared Documents"

when i save the word document back to the sharepoint library
[image]

The content type property in the word document is selected as "BZ Excel Document" but the default content types for the document library is "BZ Document"
[image]

The issue is that why 'BZ Excel Document" content type selected in the word properties as a content type when the default content type is is "BZ Document"

Answer (score 0):

What the document template you used?

Please go to library settings->click the “BZ Powerpoint Document”content type->Advanced settings->check if the document template is the custom word template you used in the Office URI schemes.

Comment: We are using document templates stored in an another sharepoint document library see url below:

word:nft|u|https://sharepoint-site-Url/Lists/Templates/CustomWordTemplate.dotm|s|https://sharepoint-site-Url/subject/1932018921/Shared Documents"